# How do commercial sauce makers have such red tomato paste?

Tags: tomatoes, color

When I make concentrated tomatoes, like for catsup, my paste comes out the color of salsa, a pale pinkish red, not the deep red you see in commercial tomato paste or catsup.

Is there a secret to making deep red tomato sauce, or are the manufacturers just adding a colorant?

Comment: The label should mention any colorants. I'd assume they just boil it to concentrate it.

Comment: I was in my supermarket 4 hours ago and read ingredients on four different brands of tomato paste. They all listed that they contained just the same two ingredients: tomato and citric acid. No colors or agents that might cause coloring are listed

Comment: Are you using home grown tomatoes or store bought? And which variety?

Comment: Tomato variety and ripeness probably play a big part in the resulting coloring

Comment: So does oxidation - which you get a lot of when eg blending a hot sauce with an immersion blender, vs blending it under vacuum (which has become recently available in home blenders).

Comment: I think it's caused by, the air in the paste. If you have a chamber vacuum sealer, try vacuuming the air out.